# Grandma's Elastic

Tags: visual, mazes

Visiting Nana is always interesting – except for last weekend.  She was busy mending some rather large item of clothing, and she said to me "Now then, you choose:  You can do the washing up (there was quite a lot), OR you can go into my black elastic drawer - and fetch me the **second largest loop** of elastic there is!  I know it's a bit of a tangle, but I'm sure a bright young mind like you can find it with no difficulty.

Fool that I am I chose the elastic. What a tedious chore!  Next time I will volunteer to do the washing up instead.

[image: draw filled with black elastic]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Nothing complicated, just loop-following:
>  [image]
>  There is one main loop coloured fuchsia above, and its removal leaves several non-entangled smaller loops. The second-longest loop is in red. Very short loops have been whited out.

Comment: Nana is so happy that she can now get on with her mending!

Comment: How did you colour them like this?

Comment: @ACB Bucket fill in GIMP. Tons of clicking.